# Compose activity not showing in New project window in Giraffe Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

After updating Flamingo to Giraffe Android studio. There is no options for compose activity in a New Project.

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996, built on June 29, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.4.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    idea.plugin.protoeditor (223.8214.6)
```

**New Project window**

[image]

What setting should I have to add in here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You literally have it selected - that's the Compose icon in the middle of Empty Activity template. With Giraffe, the default template uses Compose (and you'd need to use the "Empty Views Activity" template to get the previous behavior).

Comment: Unsolicited feedback for the tools team: whether in the caption, in a tooltip, or in a similar affordance, say that the template uses Compose. Newcomers may not recognize the icon.

Comment: Yeah it works, but for new comer will not understand.

Comment: A "new comer" does not know what Compose is either. All they need to know is that what they select from that template is the default option for Android development, which it is as of Giraffe.

Answer (score 0):

The "Empty Activity" is @Composable by default in Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) and later. So the template you're looking for is Empty Activity.

Probably like you, since that activity description is not very informative I also thought it was just completely empty. Instead, when I created a new project with the Empty Activity I got this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    MyAppTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```